# How to fix MATLAB R2014 greek letter/latex font support

Tags: fonts, latex, matlab

I am using MATLAB R2014a under Ubuntu 12.04.

Using tex markup such as \alpha, etc in text objects renders regular ASCII characters and not the expected tex output.

Making a symbolic link from the MATLAB font folder to the system font folder (as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=818607)) did not help.

Google has lots of complicated solutions to similar but more difficult problems with MATLAB/LaTeX support.

How can I get basic greek letter support in text objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing some additional X fonts as described [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/1238-font-size-changes-in-figures) solved the problem with greek letters, and also made the default font a better looking font than the monospaced font that was being used before.

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-base xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
```

xfonts-base was already at the newest version, so I think it was just the other two that made a difference. Remember to log out and log in to make the changes effective