# Ubuntu 14.04 Mathematica symbol problem

Tags: software-installation

[image: Mathematica snapshot]

How to fix mathematica symbol problem? "[" or "{" or "=" etc. are not showing. I can not find it out, why is is happening. Please help me, how to get out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link with the same question on ubuntuforums.org

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157550

It links to the following webpage with the actual solution:

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=103877#p496207

Check it out and hopefully it will solve the problem.

Good luck!

ps. also check here:

[How to fix MATLAB R2014 greek letter/latex font support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448340/how-to-fix-matlab-r2014-greek-letter-latex-font-support)